# SSIS does not read row and column delimiters

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

I have a text file with column delimiter as | (Pipe) and row delimiter as CRLF (new Line character).  The output is an SQL table.
If my data in file has more pipes(|) or more CRLF characters then my connection manager reads as follows:-

1. Data in file. In Correct format. Then the output in the table is right.

   ```
   [Global Unique Identifier]|[KPI Name]|[KPI Description]|[Process Impacted]|
   [Objective]|[Strategy ID]|[KPI Category]|[KPI Measure Type]
   A26|name|Desc|TPI|YYY|12|CAT|MT
   A27|name|Desc|TPI|YYY|12|CAT|MT
   A28|name|Desc|TPI|YYY|12|CAT|MT
   ```
2. Data in file with more column delimiters in 2nd row as below

   ```
   A26|name|Desc|TPI|YYY|12|CAT|MT
   A27|name|Desc|TPI|YYY|12|CAT|MT|||||||||
   A28|name|Desc|TPI|YYY|12|CAT|MT
   ```

   The output in file is also as above. i.e. 2nd row’s last column has all pipe lines also considered as data.
3. Data in file is as below. i.e. With just one column in the first row and we will not give other column delimiters and give row delimiter.

   ```
    A26
    A27|name|Desc|TPI|YYY|12|CAT|MT
    A28|name|Desc|TPI|YYY|12|CAT|MT
   ```

Then the output in the file is as below. We get the first column merge into the 2nd row’s first column.

```
A26 A27|name|Desc|TPI|YYY|12|CAT|MT
A28|name|Desc|TPI|YYY|12|CAT|MT
```

SSIS expects the right delimiters, only then it gives the correct output. Else the data coming in the output table is incorrect.
Can this be handled in any way?

I will be thankful in case of any help regarding this issue.

Comment: `Attached in this email` ??

Comment: @praveen pls check now its a typo:)

Comment: AFAIK  there is no way in SSIS to read the row values without proper `delimeters` .You need to roll out your own parser in C# or VB and then read individual rows  in `Script component`

Comment: Question: What would you like to do if a file has some bad rows? Do you want to process the god rows, and put the bad rows in a separate file/table? OR, do you want to not process such files at all?

Answer (score 1):

This can be a good starting point for you.

1. I used the following file as the source. Saved it into C:\Temp\1.TXT

> [Global Unique Identifier]|[KPI Name]|[KPI Description]|[Process
>   Impacted]|[Objective]| Strategy ID]|[KPI Category]|[KPI Measure Type]
>
> ```
> A26|name1|Desc|TPI|YYY|12|CAT|MT
> A27|name2|Desc|TPI|YYY|12|CAT|MT
> A28|name3|Desc|TPI|YYY|12|CAT|MT
> B26|name4|Desc|TPI|YYY|12|CAT|MT
> B27|name5|Desc|TPI|YYY|12|CAT|MT|||||||||
> B28|name6|Desc|TPI|YYY|12|CAT|MT
> C26
> C27|name7|Desc|TPI|YYY|12|CAT|MT
> C28|name8|Desc|TPI|YYY|12|CAT|MT
> ```

1. Put a DFT on the Control Flow surface.
2. Put  Script Component as Source on the DFT

   3.1. Go to Inputs and Outputs section

   3.2. Add Output. Name it GoodRow.

   ```
    3.2.1 Add the following output columns - GUID, KPIN, KPID, PI, Obj, SID, KPIC, KPIMT
   ```

   3.3  Add another output. Name it BadRow.
        3.3.1 Add just one output column: AllFields
3. Now go to Scripts // Edit Script. Put the following code. Make sure to add

> using System.IO;

to the namespace area.

```
public override void CreateNewOutputRows()
{

    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\temp\1.txt");

    int iRowCount = 0;
    int iFieldCountHeader = 0;
    string[] fields = null;


    foreach (string line in lines)
    {
        if (iRowCount == 0)
        {
            iFieldCountHeader = line.Split('|').Length;
            iRowCount++;
        }
        else
        {
            fields = line.Split('|');

            if (fields.Length == iFieldCountHeader) // good row
            {
                GoodRowBuffer.AddRow();

                GoodRowBuffer.GUID = fields[0];
                GoodRowBuffer.KPIN = fields[1];
                GoodRowBuffer.KPID = fields[2];
                GoodRowBuffer.PI = fields[3];
                GoodRowBuffer.Obj = fields[4];
                GoodRowBuffer.SID = fields[5];
                GoodRowBuffer.KPIC = fields[6];
                GoodRowBuffer.KPIMT = fields[7];
            }
            else // bad row
            {
                BadRowBuffer.AddRow();

                BadRowBuffer.AllFields = line;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

1. Testing your code: Add Two Union All components right beneath where you put the Script component.. Name one as GoodRows and the other as BadRows. Connect the two outputs of the Script component to these Union All components. Put data viewer.

Hopefully this should help you. Please let us know.

PS: When you add a Script component as Source, there is a default output. Delete it and then create the two outputs mentioned above. I know you you would done that, but just to make sure...